# Programming Principles & Practices Using C++ - Ch 04 'Try This' exercise

Tags: c++, while-loop

I'm a bit confused about this exercise in the above mentioned book-

"The character **'b'** is **char('a'+ 1)**, **'c'** is **char('a'+ 2)**, etc.  Use a loop to write out a table of characters with their corresponding integer values:

a    97

b    98

c    99

...

z    122"

The book has just gone over **while** loops, and I read a bit ahead as I was still confused as to how to do this without just listing out each value individually (which I assume isn't the point here), and the next section is about **for** loops.  I thought that maybe you can somehow increase letters in the alphabet by 1 in a loop (so a -> b, b -> c, etc.), but if this is indeed possible, the book hasn't yet gone over how to accomplish this yet.

Thanks in advance, I'm working through this book alone in my spare time so I don't have a professor to ask questions like this, and the Try This exercises don't have their answers listed on Bjarne's website.

Comment: What is you question?

Comment: Google search for a ASCII table. The 'char' type is actually an 8-bit integer that covers the whole range of the ASCII

Comment: @SamMokari My question is how to accomplish this task.  I'm sorry that I wasn't very specific, I guess I'm just missing something here.  I don't understand how to write a program that accomplishes the task mentioned above- " Use a loop to write out a table of characters with their corresponding integer values:"  The table of characters part is what confuses me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
char ch = 'a';
for (int i = 0; i < 26; ++i)
    cout << (char)(ch + i) << " " << (ch + i) << endl;
```

This will generate the output that you expect.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  This seems to output the correct numbers, however for the letters it just repeats the letter 'b' on every single line.

Comment: EDIT- I spoke too earliy.  I read (ch + i) as (ch + 1), your code does work.  If you wouldn't mind, could you explain to me why this works in beginner terms?  I still feel like I'm not fully understand it and I'd like to.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: @mstombock05 `ch + i` adds the loop index to the ASCII code of the character (i.e. 97 for 'a'). If we typecast it to `char`, the character with the ASCII is written, otherwise the code is written to output.

Answer (score 3):

Just write a simple loop:

```
for(auto c = 'a';c <= 'z' ;c++)
    cout<<c<<" "<<int(c)<<endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution to your problem :)

```
int main (void) {
  char c = 'a';

  while (c <= 'z')  {
    std::cout << c << "\t" << c - 0 << '\n'; // c - 0 is convertion to int without cast
    ++c;
  }   

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `+c` is another way to achieve that promotion. By the way, your version misses out the `z` case.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I know about promotion you are talking about, there is 3 or 4 ways of doing it. Thank you for `z` case. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

The book is referring to the idea that you can iterate over integers and use the control variable in character arithmetic to get the table.  For example, with integers you can iterate over the integers 0 to 25 with

```
int i = 0;
while (i <= 25) {
  cout << i << endl;
  i = i + 1; // or ++i
}
```

Now you can apply the problem hint `char('a' + i)` to get the rest of the answer. I'll let you work that out.

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
    int main()
    {
        char ch = 'a';
        int i = 0;
        while(i < 26)
        {
            cout << (char)(ch + i) << "\t" << (ch + i) << "\n";
            ++i;
        }
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it using the `while` loop:

```
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    int i = 0; //Initialize i to 0.

    while (i < 26) // 0 - 25.
    {
        int val = 'a' + i; // char('a' + 1), int('a' + 1). 
        std::cout << char(val) <<  "\t" << int(val) << std::endl;
        ++i; //Increments the while loop variable i
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
a       97
b       98
c       99
d       100
e       101
f       102
g       103
h       104
i       105
j       106
k       107
l       108
m       109
n       110
o       111
p       112
q       113
r       114
s       115
t       116
u       117
v       118
w       119
x       120
y       121
z       122
```

Answer (score -1):

I included comments so that you can understand my thoughts and also so that it can be updated.

Here's the answer to the Chapter 4 Try this exercise for the book by Bjarne Stroustrup: Programming Principles and Practice Using C++:

---

```
    // Description- Try this exercise using a while statement to provide a series of characters from the ASCII code.
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include "Std_lib_facilities.h"
    int main()

{
    int i = 96; // Beginning/initialisation of the integers which will be converted to char (s) in cout.

    while (i<122) // The limit for the while statement is the integer which will be safely converted to the last char.
    {
        cout << i + 1 << '\t'<< char (i+1)<<'\n'; ++i; // The first integer will be 1 plus the initial = 97. Then followed by a tab. 
                                                       // Then followed by the integer 97 being safely converted to an char using the ASCII.
                                                       // The while loop in the two comments is repeated till 122 is converted safely to z.

    }
}
```

---

Comment: Please don't promote poor coding practices. Those magic numbers are a terrible idea.